# How to select values in a matrix by a condition

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I have an algorithm and I'm trying to implement it in R:

```
object :matrix(V)
if V[1,1] > 1 then select row.name[1,1] else
if V[1,2] > 1 then select ...
```

I tried to write this way, but it wasn't working well.

```
    v
              Comp 1    Comp 2
Coliformes 2.34387737 1.7070448
DBO        0.03067654 0.6291745
OD         0.13726407 0.1972502
NO3        0.07250923 0.8988905
NO2        0.97224048 0.9616424
NH4        1.61238684 1.6422081
PO4        0.36423502 0.3688056
pH         0.98055981 1.0106563
Temp       0.10056242 0.2551496
Turb       0.76414630 0.5732596
PT         0.49795469 1.2924590

f<-subset(v>1) 

> f
           Comp 1 Comp 2
Coliformes   TRUE   TRUE
DBO         FALSE  FALSE
OD          FALSE  FALSE
NO3         FALSE  FALSE
NO2         FALSE  FALSE
NH4          TRUE   TRUE
PO4         FALSE  FALSE
pH          FALSE   TRUE
Temp        FALSE  FALSE
Turb        FALSE  FALSE
PT          FALSE   TRUE
```

Maybe my question could be simple to solve, but I have no experience with R.

Comment: As you can view i the ouput `f`, there are rows with a single `TRUE`.  Do you want to keep those rows?  If you need to extract only the TRUE values, in each column, the ouput will be better in a `list`

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're after, but maybe `subset(v, Comp1 > 1 | Comp2 > 1)` (assuming you changed the names "Comp 1" and "Comp 2" to remove spaces, which are just a hassle).

Comment: @Frank and if you didn't remove the spaces, ``subset(v, `Comp 1` > 1 | `Comp 2` > 1)``

Comment: Now, I have an object (F) with "0" instead of numbers < 1, but i Want just the row names of the rows where the numbers are >1, the value is not important from now, i want just an automatic way to keep the row names (Coliformes, DBO, pH, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
v[v > 1]
```

Or

```
f <- ifelse(v > 1, v, 0)
```